# jquery $.getJSON, retrieving servlet parameters upon process method

Tags: java, jquery, tomcat

Is this the correct way to set parameters upon a servlet request (tags, tagmode, format)?

```
$.getJSON('....Servlet',
            {
              tags: "cat",
              tagmode: "any",
              format: "json"        
            }, function(data) {
});
```

And can I retrieve the parameters like this (Servlet class extending HttpServlet | inside process method)?

```
request.getParameter("tags");
request.getParameter("tagmode");
request.getParameter("format");
```

I haven't found the right terms to search google or stackoverflow. So if anyone has a proper answer or documentation to this issue, then just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be all correct.  And BTW, you could have answered your own question if you had just written the code and tried it. ;o)

Comment: I did, but something went wrong. At least I know, I'm on the right path. And thank you...